# Javascript how to use new Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class DataBase {
    constructor(id){
        this.id='123';
}

get_id() { return "testing";}

}

class User {constructor(database) {
this.__database=database;
console.log(this.__database.id);
this.initfunc();
}
    initfunc(){this[`get_id`]=new Function(`return this.__databse.get_id()`);
}
}
var database=new DataBase();
var user =new User(database);
console.log(user.get_id());
```

Any one know how to use the new Function , if the result is correct will return the string testing, any one know how to do , please help , thanks

the expect result is console.log(user.get_id()) will show "testing" but now return error (undefined:2
return this.__databse.get_id()
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_id' of undefined)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What problem are you running into? What happens? What do you expect to happen? How do they differ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have updated the question

Comment: Well, other than some obvious issues, you've misspelled `__databse`. The error is a dead give-away that `get_id()` can't be called on something undefined.

Comment: Btw, the use of Function looks totally unjustified here. Eval is evil.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code __databse should read database

```
class DataBase {
    constructor(id){
        this.id='123';
}

get_id() { return "testing";}

}

class User {constructor(database) {
this.__database=database;
console.log(this.__database.id);
this.initfunc();
}   
    // typo below 
    initfunc(){this[`get_id`]=new Function(`return this.__database.get_id()`);
}
}
var database=new DataBase();
var user =new User(database);
console.log(user.get_id());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: Your implementation is not exactly the right way to do this. As per comments. My answer is merely a fix on your code. Just so that is clear for any future reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite mysterious what you are trying to accomplish. From the constructor, you are invoking a method, which is apparently trying to create another method. Why not just define the method as usual?

```js
    class DataBase {
      constructor(id){
        this.id='123';
      }
      get_id() { return "testing"; }
    }

    class User {
      constructor(database) {
        this.__database=database;
        console.log(this.__database.id);
      }
      get_id() { return this.__database.get_id(); }
    }

    var database=new DataBase();
    var user =new User(database);
    console.log(user.get_id());
```

As a general rule of thumb, you could program in JS for years and never find a legitimate reason to use `new Function`.

If for some strange reason you really wanted to maintain your current structure, of a method setting up another method, then just specify the function as

```
initfunc() { 
  const self = this;
  this[`get_id`] = function() {
    return self.__database.get_id();
  };
}
```

Or you could skip all the `self` business by using an arrow function:

```
initfunc() { this[`get_id`] = () => this.__database.get_id(); }
```